# cant to connect absolute import in ts

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, absolute-path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Thz.jpg)

in the photo is the whole essence of the problem, tell me what will help to solve it?

probably something in the assembly causes a conflict because of which the path does not work, but I am not sure

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about **not** posting error messages and code only as pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your App.tsx, it looks like you just forgot the './' before 'Pages' in the import. I assume you want to import those exports from the Pages directory similar to the line right above it: `import MainLayout from './Layout/MainLayout`

So try `import { Home, Dogs, About, Support} from './Pages'`